# How to resolve the error "Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry " while trying to login to heroku on Windows via Heroku CLI

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-cli

I am having trouble trying to deploy my Django app to Heroku. I am using visual studio code IDE on Windows 10. I have installed Heroku CLI but seems it's not pointing to the Heroku PATH or maybe something not set right. I am unable to login. All my search results are suggesting solutions around Node JS yet am not using Node.js.Here is the error message.

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program
> Files\heroku\client\node_modules\debug\node_modules\ms\index'. Please
> verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
>
> ```
> at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:319:19)
> at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:18)
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:27)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
> at setup (C:\Program Files\heroku\client\node_modules\debug\src\common.js:14:25)
> at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\heroku\client\node_modules\debug\src\node.js:236:37)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10) {
> ```
>
> code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', path: 'C:\Program
> Files\heroku\client\node_modules\debug\node_modules\ms\package.json',
> requestPath: 'ms' }

Comment: Please add the error as text to the question, not as an image.

Comment: Can you post your package.json file contents?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm also having the same problem!!